# Trouble to impliment scipy interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, scientific-computing

I am trying to use the class shown [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) to interpolate some data.

I am having trouble getting this class to work. A minimal example is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from mayavi.mlab import *
from mayavi import mlab
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from mayavi.scripts import mayavi2
from mayavi.sources.vtk_file_reader import VTKFileReader
from mayavi.modules.outline import Outline
from mayavi.modules.grid_plane import GridPlane
from mayavi.modules.contour_grid_plane import ContourGridPlane
from mayavi.modules.iso_surface import IsoSurface
from mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane import ScalarCutPlane
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
#from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator



print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

if (len(sys.argv)==5):
  NX = int(sys.argv[1])
  NY = int(sys.argv[2])
  NZ = int(sys.argv[3])
  fname = sys.argv[4]
else:
      print "Error in parsing the command line arguments"
      print "Command line arguments are: N_X N_Y N_Z filename "
      sys.exit()

clf()
figure(bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
len(sys.argv)

data =  genfromtxt(fname)
x,y,z = mgrid[ 0:NX:1, 0:NY:1, 0:NZ:1 ]
#print(x)
index = 0

V=0*x

for k in range(NZ):
    for j in range(NY):
        for i in range(NX):
            V[i][j][k] = 1000*data[index,5]

scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator(V, V, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan) #ERROR
```

The only bits really of interest to my current problem are the last line and all the import commands at the beginning

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "contour-3d.py", line 70, in <module>
scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator(W, W, method='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=nan)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RegularGridInterpolator'
```

I'm not too familiar with python, so this may be a very basic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> New in version 0.14.

It's likely you have a previous version of SciPy. If you are using Ubuntu, try running `pip`:

```
pip install --user --upgrade scipy
```

You might need some additional dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc gfortran python-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev cython
```

For more information see http://www.scipy.org/install.html and http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` is a new function in `scipy` `0.14.x`. You are likely to be using a older version. Updating `scipy` should solve the problem.